# Saving a Struct in a database file in C

Tags: c, database, struct, tree, save

I would like to save a struct into a db file (or .txt that doesn matter still!) but I ve got the following problem. I ve wanted to create structs inside structs like the following code.

```
typedef struct classes cl;
typedef struct attribute a;

struct classes{  \\where "a" is a type of struct
    a hunter;
    a channeler;
    a warrior;
    a rogue; };


struct human{     \\where "cl" is type of struct classes (
cl Borderlands;
cl Shienear;
cl Arafel;
cl Illian;
cl Tear;
cl Tarabon;
cl Andor;
cl TwoRivers;
cl Amandor;
cl Mayene;
cl Murandy;
};
```

The question is if i have a variable
    struct human data
do i have to save all the branches of the tree(as i think that it is a tree that i have created), or by just saving the root, do I save the whole struct?

P.S. please excuse my way of writting, i am not that experienced in programming

Answer (score 2):

You should make save method for every structure like this:

```
void save_h(human * h, FILE * stream)
{
    save_cl(h->Borderlands,stream);
    save_cl(h->Shienear,stream);
    save_cl(h->Arafel,stream);
    save_cl(h->Illian,stream);
    save_cl(h->Tear,stream);
    save_cl(h->Tarabon,stream);
    ...
}

void save_cl(classes * cl, FILE * stream)
{
    save_a(cl->hunter,stream);
    save_a(cl->channeler,stream);
    save_a(cl->warrior,stream);
    save_a(cl->rogueon,stream);
    ...
}

void save_a(attribute * a, FILE * stream)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: This question is tagged C, not C++. Function overloading is not available in C.

Comment: Also note that this is not very flexible. It would be a pain to add another struct type to the list.

Comment: Ofcourse, it is not extendable. Is it possible to save tree such way, that it's growing will be like "appendix" in storage?

Answer (score 1):

If you have simple structs with no pointers, fixed size field types and are not planning to move this data onto other machines, you can just simply write entire structure to a binary file since it has linear representation in memory. And read it back the same way. Otherwise, read about marshaling and unmarshaling data. If you don't understand this concept none of the code is actually very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

```
#define STRUCTFLAG 565719 // some random number

// NOTE: This is based on the idea that sizeof(int) == sizeof(int *). 
// If this is wrong, then make the type of variables such that 
// sizeof(typeof variable) = sizeof(int *).
struct basestruct {
    int flag; // when initialized, this has the value of STRUCTFLAG, so that we know it's a struct
    int size; // total size of the struct, in bytes. set when struct is created.

    // all other variables in the struct are either pointers to other structs or of the primitive type of the size 'int *'.
}

struct mystruct {
    int flag;
    int size;

    struct mystruct2 *variable1;
    struct mystruct3 *variable2;
}

int isStruct(const void *structAddr)
{
    int *casted = (int *) structAddr;
    return casted[0] == STRUCTFLAG;
}
void saveStruct(FILE *file, const void *structaddr)
{
    // make sure it's a struct
    if (isStruct(structaddr))
    {            
        int *casted = (int *) structaddr;
        fprintf(file, "%i\n", casted[0]); // print flag

        casted++; // skip 'flag';

        fprintf(file, "%i\n", casted[0]); // print size
        int numVariables = ((casted[0] / sizeof(int)) - 2);

        casted++;

        for (int i = 0; i < numVariables; i++)
        {
            if (isStruct(casted + i))
            {
                saveStruct(file, casted + i);
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(file, "%i\n", casted[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // report error
    }
}
```

Good luck reading it back in though. You only asked how to save it!

Comment: `sizeof(int) == sizeof(int *)` is a terrible assumption to make. And even if you change `int` to `intptr_t`, you won't be able to transfer your saved files between machines.

Comment: I also don't like the unstated requirement that no variable will ever happen to have the value `STRUCTFLAG` - it will cause random-looking and possibly hard to reproduce failures.

Comment: @interjay true, but this was the first idea I had. While not portable, it is a simple implementation, and is workable for smaller data structures.

Comment: @interjay also true. I did not say that this method does not have it's caveats and possible bugs, but it's a flexible down-and-dirty solution.